# Joining Two Tables to a Reference Table Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I Have three tables

#1 Table **timeline** which is my reference table with an Auto incremented ID which is stored in column *id*

#2 **timeline_videos**

#3 **timeline_else**

What happens is on post if a video is uploaded with the post 
    it will go into Table #2 ,anything else goes into Table #3.

#2-3 have the Auto Increment Id from the Table **timeline** stored in a column *pid*

On query of The Timeline I need to join both tables data using id=pid 
     so I can use the rest of the Relational Data with the post.
   I have done a bit of research and can't seem to find a method for doing so.
So far the code I have

**Controller**

```
$groupposts = timeline::where([
    ['owner','=',$owner],['id','<',$lastid],
    ])
    ->join('timeline_videos','timeline.id','=','timeline_videos.pid')
    //->join('timeline_else','timeline.id','=','timeline_else.pid')
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->limit(5)
    ->get();
```

This works with no errors with the second Join commented out but I need to also grab the **timeline_else** data .

### Update --

I have now decided to use Eloquent Relationships to join the tables,
  my question now is what type of relationship do I have between the 
  tables? 
 I realize it basically needs to be able to switch between two tables to 
  grab data based on the fact that **timeline_videos** and **timeline_else** will not be "JOIN" but separated by type . 
 The tables need to Join with table #1 **timeline** based on a column I now have named **type** for clarifying where to look and matching/joining using the **id = pid**

Comment: Try left join for `timeline_else`

Comment: IT WORKED lol so much time and that was it thank you !

Comment: or you could just use relationships to get the needed information

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but wasn't for sure how to come close to what I wanted with using Eloquent and having Relations between each table @ParkerDell

Comment: @ParkerDell What type of Eloquent Relationship is this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using some of what **Parker Dell** supplied and a bit more trial and error

My Models  Looks like

**timeline**

```
 class timeline extends Model
{
  protected $table ='timeline';
  public $timestamps = false;

  public function videos()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\timeline_videos','pid','id');
  }
  public function else()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\timeline_ect','pid','id');
  }

}
```

**timeline_ect.php ,I changed the name of the table**

```
class timeline_ect extends Model
{
    protected $table='timeline_ect';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function timeline()
      {
          return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\timeline','pid','id');
      }
}
```

**timeline_videos**

```
  class timeline_videos extends Model
{
    protected $table='timeline_videos';
    public $timestamps = false;
 public function timeline()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\timeline','id','pid');
   }
}
```

Then Lastly my Controller

```
$timeline = timeline::with('videos','else')
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->limit(5)
    ->get();
```

So far no Problem query is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relationships.

it sounds like timelines has many videos and has many video failures 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

you would have a model for each table and set up the relationships

timelines model:

```
public function videos()
{
    return $this-> hasMany('App\Videos');
}
public function videoFailures()
{
    return $this-> hasMany('App\videoFailures');
}
```

videos model:

```
public function timeline()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Timelines');
}
```

videos failures model:

```
public function timeline()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Timelines');
}
```

You can then go:

```
 $timeLine = Timmeline::find($id);
```

to find videos of the time lines you would do:

```
$videos = $timeLine->videos();
```

to find else:

```
$videoElse = $timeLine-> videoFailures();
```